# Automator action to upload a file/folder

Tags: automator, folders, data-transfer, file, macos

Is there an Automator action that can upload a file/folder?

Specifically, I want to upload a folder automatically at a set date/time. I know I can create a "Calendar Alarm" action that'll trigger based on a calendar event – but I don't actually see an action that can upload to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Automator's **Run Shell Script** step with the command line tool `curl`.

[curl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/curl.1.html) can upload files using the `-F` flag followed by a file path. See ariejan de vroom's [uploading files with Curl](http://ariejan.net/2010/06/07/uploading-files-with-curl/) for an example.

Your shell script can be passed a list of files from earlier Automator steps:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    curl -i -F "$f" http://example.org/upload
done
```